# JSF beans and object

Tags: jsf, javabeans, managed-bean

I have a JSF project, and I am trying to do a login page, in my project I have a managed bean that has a validate method for the username and password, and I have a bean class with setters and getters which has the user info that get filled for a database eg.(username, password, isActive, Full name), my question is how can I call the user info in JSF el expression in my xhtml pages if they are not in the managed bean?

Here is my java bean:

```
@Table(name="students_info")
public class User {
    @Column(name="std_record_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="std_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="web_password")
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And here is my MBLogin:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class MBLogin {

        User user = new User();
        LoginDAO loginDao = new LoginDAO();

        public String validteStudent() {
            boolean valid = loginDao.validateStudent(user.getUserId(), user.getUserId());
            if (valid) {
                HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username", user);
                return "student";
            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                        "Incorrect Username and Passowrd", "Please enter correct username and Password"));
                return "login";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: without getting to managed bean at all??

Comment: @khalilM I want to access the managed bean, and was able to access them only if I duplicated my instance variables and setters and getters in the managed bean, but this make no sense right? I am sorry but I am new to JSF

Comment: @luudvankeulen Here I updated my post

Comment: In your code the user is in your managedbean. Just create a getter for the user and you can call it in the xhtml as: `#{user.id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getter for the user:

```
@ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class MBLogin {

        User user = new User();
        LoginDAO loginDao = new LoginDAO();

        public String validteStudent() {
            boolean valid = loginDao.validateStudent(user.getUserId(), user.getUserId());
            if (valid) {
                HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username", user);
                return "student";
            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                        "Incorrect Username and Passowrd", "Please enter correct username and Password"));
                return "login";
            }
        }
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Then in your xhtml you can call it like this:
`#{user.id}`, `#{user.firstName}`

Comment: Thanks sir that worked fine :D

Comment: that worked for my getters but now my setters are not working is there any way to fix them?

Comment: Just add a setter to the managedbean.

Comment: Thanks sir the only thing left now is #{user.firstName} is not priniting any thing and I am sure that it has a value as Its printing out using    System.out.println(user.getFirstName()); in my dao class can you suggest why is that happening I would really appreciate it.